# Any disadvantage of using ExecuteReaderAsync from C# AsyncCTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, async-await

There are some articles which indicate that async database calls are bad idea in .NET.

- [Should my database calls be Asynchronous?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/11/14/should-my-database-calls-be-asynchronous.aspx)
- [Should my database calls be Asynchronous Part II](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/07/19/should-my-database-calls-be-asynchronous-part-ii.aspx)

On C# Async CTP, there is a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` extension called `ExecuteReaderAsync`. I have some operations as below on my existing code:

```
var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hubConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) {

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp$DetailsTagsGetAllFromApprovedPropsWithCount";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        conn.Open();

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) {

            //do the reading

        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

There are several operations like this on my code. So, I am having thoughts on converting those to async.

But on the other hand, I am not seeing much attraction on this approach out there (maybe I am not looking at the right direction, who knows!).

So, is there any disadvantages of using this new async programming model here?

**Edit:**

Assuming I refactor the code as below:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> GetDataAsync() { 

    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

    var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hubConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) {

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp$DetailsTagsGetAllFromApprovedPropsWithCount";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            conn.Open();

            var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while (reader.Read()) {

                //do the reading
                //create foos

            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    return foos;

}
```

As far as I understand from the await keyword, it converts the code, which is after it, as continuation. Also, when it hits the await keyword, it immediately returns to its caller regardless of the operation status. When it finishes it comes back and fire the continuation code.

This is what I have in mind.

Comment: Although the accepted answer is perfect, i would like to add my example. In my website, i made all the action methods as Task<ActionResult> and made all the db calls async. The website really started loading faster

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I disagree with Ricka on this. Async DB commands are not only good, they are critical in achieving scale, throughput *and* latency. His objection about the ramp up time of the thread pool applies only to a web server that experiences low traffic volumes.

In a high traffic situation (which is the only one that matters), the thread pool won't have to wait for 'injecting' new threads. Doing the SQL Commands asynchronously is important not only from the point of view of web server requests/threads health, but also from the point of view of total request lifetime/latency: uncorrelated DB calls can be done in parallel, as opposed to sequentially. This alone results usually in dramatic improvements in the latency of the HTTP request as experienced by the user. In other words, your pages load faster.

A word of advice though: SQL Command is not truly asynchronous until you enable [`Asynchronous Processing=true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.asynchronousprocessing.aspx) on the connection string. While this is not set (and by default is not, *Edit: starting with .NET Framework < 4.5.   [`Asynchronous Processing` is no longer required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.asynchronousprocessing.aspx)*) your 'asyncronous' calls to [`BeginExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader.aspx) are nothing but a sham, the call will launch a thread and block *that* thread. When true async processing is enabled *in the connection string* then the call is truly async and the callback is based on IO completion.

A word of caution: an async SQL command is completing as soon as the *first* result returns to the client, and info messages count as result.

```
create procedure usp_DetailsTagsGetAllFromApprovedPropsWithCount
as
begin
print 'Hello';
select complex query;
end
```

You've lost all benefits of async. The `print` creates a result that is sent back to the client, which completes the async command and execution on the client resumes and continues with the 'reader.Read()'. Now *that* will block until the complex query start producing results. You ask *'who puts `print` in the procedure?'* but the `print` may be disguised in something else, perhaps something as innocent looking as an `INSERT` that executes *without* first issuing a [`SET NOCOUNT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx).

Comment: *"Command is not truly asynchronous until you enable Asynchronous Processing=true on the connection string."* Is it still applicable if I use the new async programming model as I indicate on my question?

Comment: Good lord who make design decisions like this? These gotchas are absurd.

Comment: @tugberk: I'm pretty sure `ExecuteReaderAsync` is nothing but a wrapper around `BeginExecuteReader`/`EndExecuteReader`, therefore the connection string requirement applies to it as well.

Comment: I don't think so (while I am not sure). New async programming model is a lot different I think. First of all, it is Task based.

Comment: Yes, but the underlying async capabilities come from the `SqlClient` component. The Async team is building the language and .Net Framework capabilities leveraging the existing `IAsyncResult` features, not reinventing each one from scratch.

Comment: yes, right. It's what it does: `public static Task<SqlDataReader> ExecuteReaderAsync(this SqlCommand source)
{
 return Task<SqlDataReader>.Factory.FromAsync(new Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult>(source.BeginExecuteReader), new Func<IAsyncResult, SqlDataReader>(source.EndExecuteReader), null);
}`

Comment: BTW as of .Net 4.5 there is new [SqlDataReader.ReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223681(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Beginning in the .NET Framework 4.5, these methods no longer require Asynchronous Processing=true in the connection string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418.aspx

Comment: Excellent, i'm beginning to use async methods for my database calls.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the following question wasn't answered:

> So, is there any disadvantages of using this new async programming model here?

The *disadvantage* which is **very minimal** (minor cpu/minor memory afaik), is that because there is the possibility of any code running after an await statement *may* run on a separate thread, a state-machine exists to store the state of the currently running thread so that the continuation of work can be handled on another thread.  You can read more about the [await/async statemachine on Dixin's Blog - Understanding C# async / await (1) Compilation](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-1-compilation).