# await operator can only be used with async methods?

Tags: c#, async-await

Hi I have created an async method is c# to get all projects from VSTS.

Here is how the defenition looks like

```
public async Task<string> GetProjects()
{
    try
    {
        return r;
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

But when I tries to get the return value from it, it says The await operator can only be used with Async methods.. I didnt understand it since Im new to these async and await methods. The way I tried to access is like this

string s;

```
s=await GetProjects();
```

Comment: You probably do `s=await GetProjects();` in non-async method. You can only use `await` in an `async` method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488677/how-does-await-async-work-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks @MikeKaskun for pointing me that.. Yea, mine was not an async method, I was not aware the calling function also has to be async.

Answer (score 2):

If you desperately need to have an async method, you can do it like this:

```
return Task.FromResult("");
```

However, you should really read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489591/383426) as @PeterBons suggested

Answer (score 0):

If your method uses `await`, it must be marked as `async`.
You can read here why: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/11/11/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-six-whither-async/