Async Programming with ADO.Net
Some years ago Remus Rusanu has posted this great answer about ADO async programming:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9434687/23900248
In particular he wrote:

A word of caution: an async SQL command is completing as soon as the first result returns to the client, and info messages count as result.
You've lost all benefits of async. The print creates a result that is sent back to the client, which completes the async command and execution on the client resumes and continues with the 'reader.Read()'. Now that will block until the complex query start producing results. You ask 'who puts print in the procedure?' but the print may be disguised in something else, perhaps something as innocent looking as an INSERT that executes without first issuing a SET NOCOUNT ON.

Now we are at .NET 8, and this situation seems to persist. Is there a workaround? What is the correct way to asynchronously call a stored procedure that produces many results, including messages that, for example, inform the client about the execution status?
In example:
declare @K int=0, @Progress varchar(255)
while @K<100
    begin

    set @K=@K+1

    select Flush=1
    set @Progress=concat('Executing ', @K, ' of 100')
    raiserror(@Progress, 9, 1) with nowait
    waitfor delay '00:00:01'
    end

marc.
UPDATE
Following the discussion with Panagiotis, I'm trying to reformulate my question. Consider the TSQL fragment mentioned above; we're not interested in whether this code is good or bad, nor are we concerned about whether it's a proper or improper use of SQL Server. The only fact I ask to focus on is that this code produces a flow of 100 result sets and 100 messages, alternated.
If it weren't for that waitfor, the code execution, transmission to the client, and client-side processing would be almost instantaneous. However, that waitfor is there and causes the processing of that stored procedure to last about 100 seconds. Almost all of this time consists of waiting for the server.
On paper, this is the ideal situation to apply async/await logic. Putting it in simplified terms: "No new thread is needed, with all its complications, we use the waiting time to do something else and not block the flow and therefore, ultimately, the interface."
And indeed, this happens if the messages are removed; ADO.Net performs that call asynchronously. But if there are messages, the mechanism gets jammed. Why?
Theoretically, datasets and messages are essentially the same thing, two chunks of data in the Pipe flowing from the server to the client. Why does a message disrupt ADO.Net?
Remus writes:

The print creates a result that is sent back to the client, which
completes the async command, and execution on the client resumes and
continues with the 'reader.Read()'. Now that will block until the
complex query starts producing results.

And Panagiotis reiterates:

Remus Rusanu warns against bad stored procedure coding, not about
issues in asynchronous programming.

However, I don't understand why the arrival of the message demands marking the command as completed. The only reason that comes to my mind is that messages, being handled for historical reasons as events, break the async/await chain.
Why does ADO lock up? And more importantly, is there a purely async/await way to prevent it from locking up?
Running the asynchronous call within Task.Run() solves the problem, but it seems if Task.Run is more efficient than the asynchronous method itself, it means that the asynchronous method is widely optimizable, right?
rimarc

What you posted isn't asynchronous programming at all, it's ugly, synchronously blocking way of "reporting progress". That alone is a bad smell that suggests the stored procedure is doing something wrong, like looping or using a cursor instead of set-based queries. Asynchronous programming means using using var reader=await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(). So what does this situation seems to persist mean?

SQL Server has a way to send notifications between processes/services since 2005, Service Broker, which provides proper queues, services, conversations. ADO.NET notifications are based on this.

The issue I raise is not about how to write a stored procedure but how to call a generic stored procedure in C# without encountering the problem pointed out by Remus. Executing an asynchronous call via .Net to that TSQL code (good or bad as it may be) causes the client to freeze and the benefits of async/await are lost (as observed by Remus). One way to circumvent this is to use Task.Run(), in this way ADO forcibly uses a new thread and the flow works properly. But what's the point? Is it not possible to asynchronously receive those results using exclusively the async/await pattern?

You aren't making an asynchronous call to a generic stored procedure. What you describe is progress reporting, not asynchronous execution. The real problem is using the wrong technique to do something that shouldn't be done this way anyway. raiserror(@Progress, 9, 1) with nowait is NOT a report mechanism

causes the client to freeze not if you actually used Execute...Async without trying to read "progress messages".

To put it another way, Remus Rusanu warns against bad stored procedure coding, not about issues in asynchronous programming.

I'll rephrase: is it possible to write a client that, like SSMS or Azure Data Studio, reports messages and results without freezing by using the asynchronous methods of ADO.Net, or is it not possible?

But SSMS don't do what you claim either. The window does freeze. The messages are received through the SqlConnection.InfoMessage event.


raiserror(@Progress, 9, 1) with nowait is NOT a report mechanism. P.S. This is exactly the strategy used by Sql Server to communicate the progress of a backup.

